# How to draw directly on the screen with wxpython?

Tags: python, drawing, wxpython, overlay

I'm using Linux and e17 with composition disabled, and I would like to create a program capable of drawing simple geometrical shapes and text directly onto the screen.

My first thought was to do:

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)
s = wx.ScreenDC()
s.Pen = wx.Pen("#FF0000")
s.DrawRectangle(60,60,120,120)
```

But this wouldn't work, so I replaced the last line with:

```
for i in range(0,129):
    s.DrawRectangle(60,60,120,120)
```

Which somehow made it work, but it's a hacky solution and to draw lines I need to increase amount of iterations even more.

I think the problem might be with transparency, but have no idea how to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your code works fine on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I assume it also works fine in most other Linux WM's and DE's. Enlightenment is somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you specify, [`StartDrawingOnTop`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ScreenDC-class.html#StartDrawingOnTop) anywhere?  Otherwise, it seems you might have a transparency issue so you might try setting that explicitly.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about that. I'm ashamed of such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could do this by creating a frame and panel and then call the frame's SetTransparency method to set that. You definitely want to use DCs or something similar like FloatCanvas to do the drawing. Worth a try anyway.

Comment: Potential lack of transparency is an issue here, but I'll try this way as it does sound like a better idea.

Comment: You can ask on the wxPython mailing list too. There's a bunch of Linux guys there and people who use the drawing capabilities of wx in wild and wooly ways.